# how to get tradingview chart data by javascript?

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

I was able to display a tradingview chart using the link below:
https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/

Now, how can use the chart data?
For example, I want to set page title by current currency price.

Comment: You should include an example of your code getting this data. It will allow people to better help answer.

Comment: i think he would like show chart of tradingview in ifame but, trading view refuse connect with it